# Salesforce1 Smart Search on Navigation menu

Tags: mobile, salesforce1-app

Having trouble customizing Smart Search for the SF1 Navigation menu.  In short, 'pinning' the object controls whether or not that object shows on the menu.  My problem is this is not consistent across all my users.  For one user it works perfect (I  can control the menu items 100%), for others I can not (menu shows all of the objects, not just the 'pinned' objects).  I've tried everything, using same Profile, same Role, same user settings.  I'm at a loss and could use some expert help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinned objects are only part of the list of Smart Scope objects. Any other objects that the  user has been interacting with over a period of time (including page views and clicks on search results) are automatically added to the Smart Scope, in addition to any pinned objects.

For the user where only the pinned objects are showing up, if they are a new user or don't have a lot of other activity in the system on other objects, that might be why no other objects are showing up.

Comment: I am having the same issues here... Our customers do not use Chatter, so no pinning in global search is non-starter. We also not use today, call history. Documentation says it can take up to 15 days for "Recent" items to populate in smart search. So initially when low activity users log in to SF1 they see absolutely nothing. In terms of simply providing mobile access to records in Salesforce.com - SF1 initially seems like a let down.